# Sending multiple files in socket client server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I would like to send multiples files on a single client server connect.  The server should accept a connection from the client and then loop through a folder and send every file in there to the client.  What is a good way to do this so that the client can save each file after receiving them and then correctly read the next file.

I have the following server code which only sends 1 file and closes.

```
/*
    Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming

    compile:
        gcc serverFile.c -o serverFile
    run:
        ./serverFile

    from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/ 
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    char *file_path = "image.jpg";
    int input_file;

    input_file = open(file_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (input_file == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    // Creating socket file descriptor. AF_INET is IPv4, SOCK_STREAM is tcp.
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Set socket option (optional?).  SOL_SOCKET is socket level argument.  
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                                 sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // If you want to read multiple server connections.
    //int x;
    //for (x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );

    /*********************** read file and send it over socket ****************************/


    //unsigned char buffer[1000];
    while (1) {
            // Read data into buffer.  We may not have enough to fill up buffer, so we
            // store how many bytes were actually read in bytes_read.
            int bytes_read = read(input_file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
                break;

            if (bytes_read < 0) {
                // handle errors
                printf("read error!\n");
            }

            // You need a loop for the write, because not all of the data may be written
            // in one call; write will return how many bytes were written. p keeps
            // track of where in the buffer we are, while we decrement bytes_read
            // to keep track of how many bytes are left to write.
            void *p = buffer;
            while (bytes_read > 0) {
                int bytes_written = write(new_socket, p, bytes_read);
                if (bytes_written <= 0) {
                    // handle errors
                }
                bytes_read -= bytes_written;
                p += bytes_written;
            }
    }

    /***************************************************************************************/

    //send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
    //printf("Hello message sent\n");

    close(new_socket);
    close(server_fd);
    //} 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the Question?

Comment: You will need to define a communication protocol that defines when a file begins and ends so that the client can tell two files apart. This may be as simple as sending size of the file before sending the file.

Comment: @JakeFreeman How to write a server code to send mutiple files in 1 connection?

Comment: @user4581301 Any chance you have example code?

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise / school homework, or do you need an actual solution? I'm asking because the design changes when you consider production applications, mostly due to  error handling, failure recovery etc'...? For real world applications I would highly recommend using existing protocols (HTTP / FTP etc'), this will help with authoring different clients as needs arise.

Comment: @Myst Not school, i'm trying write program to download bunch of images from a raspberry pi to pc.  What do you suggest to use as protocol???  This is for a production application.

Comment: @bakalolo - I would use other HTTP(S) or a combination of HTTP(S) and Websockets for a production application as you describe. There are existing HTTP/Websocket solutions for embedded systems, so you'll be getting a head start. Also, HTTP/1.1 (and up) supports partial downloads (allowing for error recovery) and Websockets will allow you an even tighter control if you want it. Also, this makes client authoring a breeze (you can have a web page served by the server act as the client or you can use a Ruby or bash script, maybe using curl).

Comment: @Myst Cool beans although I don't think I have enough time to look into it since I need to get this done asap since i have almost 0 experience in protocols etc..How long you think will take me to learn this if I have no experience HTTPS to get something working?

Comment: @bakalolo - I'm the author of [facil.io](http://facil.io), so I might be biased... but if you install a Linux flavored OS on your Pi (I think most of the OS options are Linux based), you should be able to start up a simple static file service using  [facil.io](http://facil.io) and maybe four lines of code or so. I'm not sure if fail.io will work on the Pi (due to possible unaligned memory access and the CPU version you have), but I'm sure other similar options exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, if anyone has any constructive criticism would love to hear.  Works fine with python client I wrote to read 10bytes (filesize), 50bytes(filename) and filesize bytes (filedata).

```
/*
    Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming

    compile:
        gcc serverMultipleFileV2.c -o serverMultipleFileV2
    run:
        ./serverMultipleFileV2

    from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/ 
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{

    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    char* hello = "Hello from server";

    // Creating socket file descriptor. AF_INET is IPv4, SOCK_STREAM is tcp.
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Set socket option (optional?).  SOL_SOCKET is socket level argument.
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
            &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address,
            sizeof(address))
        < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address,
             (socklen_t*)&addrlen))
        < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    /*********************** read file and send it over socket *************************/

    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* ent;

    if ((dir = opendir("images/")) == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open directory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // loop through folder and read /send all files.
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {

        if (!strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")) {
            continue;
        }

        // get the filename e.g. [CAM1]image6-2017-12-13-21-32-24.jpg
        char file_name[50];
        strncpy(file_name, ent->d_name, 49);
        file_name[49] = '\0';

        // get the filepath e.g. images/[CAM1]image6-2017-12-13-21-32-24.jpg
        char pathname[80];
        char * filename = "images/";
        strcpy(pathname, filename);
        strcat(pathname, file_name);

        printf("FILENAME: %s\n", file_name);
        printf("PATHNAME: %s\n", pathname);

        // open file for read
        int input_file;
        input_file = open(pathname, O_RDONLY);
        if (input_file == -1) {
            printf("Couldn't read file!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /*********Send filesize over socket*****/
        // get filesize
        struct stat st;
        stat(pathname, &st);
        long file_size = (long)st.st_size;
        char fileSizeString[10];
        // convert file_size to string
        const int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", file_size);
        assert(n > 0);
        int c = snprintf(fileSizeString, n + 1, "%lu", file_size);
        assert(fileSizeString[n] == '\0');
        assert(c == n);
        printf("file size:%s\n", fileSizeString);
        int bytes_written = write(new_socket, fileSizeString, sizeof(fileSizeString));

        /*********Send filename over socket*****/
        bytes_written = write(new_socket, file_name, sizeof(file_name));

        /*********Send filedata over socket*****/
        while (1) {
            // Read data into buffer.  We may not have enough to fill up buffer, so we
            // store how many bytes were actually read in bytes_read.
            int bytes_read = read(input_file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
                break;

            if (bytes_read < 0) {
                // handle errors
                printf("read error!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            // You need a loop for the write, because not all of the data may be written
            // in one call; write will return how many bytes were written. p keeps
            // track of where in the buffer we are, while we decrement bytes_read
            // to keep track of how many bytes are left to write.
            void* p = buffer;
            while (bytes_read > 0) {
                int bytes_written = write(new_socket, p, bytes_read);
                if (bytes_written <= 0) {
                    // handle errors
                }
                bytes_read -= bytes_written;
                p += bytes_written;
            }

        } 

    }
    closedir(dir);
    close(new_socket); //close connection with specific client
    close(server_fd); // close connection to stop listening

    return 0;
}
```

python client

```
# Read header size and multiple file data over tcp socket
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys
import string

TCP_IP = '192.168.0.102'
TCP_PORT = 8080

MESSAGE = "Hello, bakalolo speaking"

#f = open('torecv.jpg','wb')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)

while(True):

    print "*************************************************"

    # ----------Read file size (10 bytes) from socket-----
    fileSizeRecievedCounter = 0 #store number of file size bytes read so far
    fileSize = "" # store file size data as string when read
    l = s.recv(10)
    # if no more data left, all images should be read from server.
    if len(l) == 0:
        break 
    fileSizeRecievedCounter += len(l) #incriment bytes read counter
    fileSize += l #concat read data to filename
    # Keep reading until we have 10 bytes just in case
    while(fileSizeRecievedCounter < 10):
        l = s.recv(10 - fileSizeRecievedCounter)
        fileSizeRecievedCounter += len(l)
        fileSize += l

    print "file sizeb4convert:", repr(l)
    l = l.split('\0', 1)[0]
    #l = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, l) #remove byte values from string
    fileSize = int(l)
    print "file size:", repr(fileSize)

    # ----------Read file name (50 bytes) from socket-----
    fileNameRecievedCounter = 0 #store number of file name bytes read so far
    fileName = ""
    # read file name
    l = s.recv(50)
    fileNameRecievedCounter += len(l) #incriment bytes read counter
    fileName += l #concat read data to filename
    while(fileNameRecievedCounter < 50):
        l = s.recv(50 - fileNameRecievedCounter)
        fileNameRecievedCounter += len(l)
        fileName += l

    print "file nameb4convert:", repr(fileName)
    fileName = fileName.split('\0', 1)[0]
    #fileName = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, l)
    print "file name:", repr(fileName)


    f = open(fileName,'wb')
    # read file data
    fileSizeRecieved = 0 #store number of bytes read so far
    l = s.recv(1024)
    f.write(l)
    fileSizeRecieved += len(l) #add bytes read to counter
    while (l):

        if fileSizeRecieved == fileSize:
            break

        bytesLeft = fileSize - fileSizeRecieved
        if bytesLeft < 1024: #if less than 1024 bytes left, read how much is left
            l = s.recv(bytesLeft)
            f.write(l)
            fileSizeRecieved += len(l)
        else:
            l = s.recv(1024)
            f.write(l)
            #print "Receiving...", len(l)
            fileSizeRecieved += len(l)

    print "Done receiving! Total:", fileSizeRecieved

f.close()
s.close()

#print "received data:", l
```